# How can I change a token type int an ANTLR3 lexer rule?

Tags: action, antlr, token, fragment, lexer

I have a lexical rule (Integer) which uses some fragments. In a parser rule (parse) I want to rewrite my tree differently depending on which fragment generated the token in question. I have made a small grammar to demonstrate what I'm attempting:

```
grammar subrange;

options {
    output=AST;
}

tokens {
    NumberNode;
    DecimalNode;
    BinaryNode;
    HexNode;
    OctalNode;
}

parse
    : Integer+ -> ^(NumberNode Integer)+
    ;

Integer
    : DECIMAL_LITERAL
    | BINARY_LITERAL
    | HEX_LITERAL
    | OCTAL_LITERAL
    ;

fragment BINARY_LITERAL
    : '2#' ('0' | '1')+
    ;

fragment HEX_LITERAL 
    : ('16#' | '0' ('x'|'X')) HEX_DIGIT+
    ;

fragment HEX_DIGIT
    : (DIGIT|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')
    ;

fragment DECIMAL_LITERAL 
    : ('0' | '1'..'9' DIGIT*)
    ;

fragment OCTAL_LITERAL 
    : '8#' ('0'..'7')+
    ;

fragment DIGIT
    : '0'..'9'
    ;

SPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

I want the *parse* rule to rewrite a DECIMAL_LITERAL under an imaginary DecimalNode but a BINARY_LITERAL under a BinaryNode (rather than everything under a NumberNode).

I'm attempting to do this by changing the token type inside the lexical rule so that I can then rewrite accordingly inside the parse rule.

I think I should be able to do this with an action but I have been unable to figure out how to find the returned token in order to change its type. http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Special+symbols+in+actions seems to indicate that $tokenref should work but it doesn't get translated at all.

Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, `DECIMAL_LITERAL -> DecimalNode` and `BINARY_LITERAL -> BinaryNode`. What about `HEX_LITERAL` and `OCTAL_LITERAL`? I also see imaginary node-tokens for those two, but you don't mention them.

Comment: Yes I didn't enumerate them all in my question but I want an imaginary node for each of those fragments. For the sake of this example I figured if I can differentiate DECIMAL_LITERAL and BINARY_LITERAL I should be able to figure out the rest :0)

Comment: For a fuller picture of my problem, see [this grammar](http://bpaste.net/show/gaVfsm3iSUekv3Elwlf7/). I want rewrite the numbers into DecimalNode, BinaryNode, OctalNode, HexNode, and FloatNode rather than having them all as NumberNode. I accomplished this initially by referring to their individual lexical rules directly from my parser rule but in order to avoid the 1..2 ambiguity I had to change them to fragments and add another lexical rule above them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bit odd to me: grouping all such literals under a single `Integer` token, and then, in a parser rule you want to separate them again.

Why not just remove `Integer` and do:

```
integer
    : BINARY_LITERAL // when output=AST, this creates a CommonTree with type 'BINARY_LITERAL'
    | HEX_LITERAL    // ...
    | DECIMAL_LITERAL
    | OCTAL_LITERAL 
    ;

BINARY_LITERAL
    : '2#' ('0' | '1')+
    ;

HEX_LITERAL 
    : ('16#' | '0' ('x'|'X')) HEX_DIGIT+
    ;

DECIMAL_LITERAL 
    : ('0' | '1'..'9' DIGIT*)
    ;

OCTAL_LITERAL 
    : '8#' ('0'..'7')+
    ;
```

?

Or you could keep the `Int(eger)` rule but set the numerical value of the various int-literals by doing:

```
Int
@init{int skip = 0, base = 10;}
    : ( DECIMAL_LITERAL
      | BINARY_LITERAL  {base = 2;  skip = 2;} 
      | OCTAL_LITERAL   {base = 8;  skip = 2;} 
      | HEX_LITERAL     {base = 16; skip = $text.contains("#") ? 3 : 2;} 
      )
      {
        setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt($text.substring(skip), base)));
      }
    ;

fragment BINARY_LITERAL
    : '2#' ('0' | '1')+
    ;

fragment HEX_LITERAL 
    : ('16#' | '0' ('x'|'X')) HEX_DIGIT+
    ;

fragment DECIMAL_LITERAL 
    : ('0' | '1'..'9' DIGIT*)
    ;

fragment OCTAL_LITERAL 
    : '8#' ('0'..'7')+
    ;
```

Be careful giving rules a name as some object/class/reserved-word of the target language can have (`Integer` in case of Java).

---

### EDIT

Okay. I'll leave my other answer there in case passers-by are wondering why on earth I'm proposing this... :)

Here's what (I think) you're after:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  BinaryNode;
  OctalNode;
  HexNode;
  DecimalNode;
}

parse
 : integer+
 ;

integer
 : i=Integer -> {$i.text.startsWith("2#")}?         ^(BinaryNode Integer)
             -> {$i.text.startsWith("8#")}?         ^(OctalNode Integer)
             -> {$i.text.matches("(16#|0[xX]).*")}? ^(HexNode Integer)
             ->                                     ^(DecimalNode Integer)
 ;

Integer
 : DECIMAL_LITERAL
 | BINARY_LITERAL
 | HEX_LITERAL
 | OCTAL_LITERAL
 ;

fragment BINARY_LITERAL
 : '2#' ('0' | '1')+
 ;

fragment HEX_LITERAL 
 : ('16#' | '0' ('x'|'X')) HEX_DIGIT+
 ;

fragment HEX_DIGIT
 : (DIGIT|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')
 ;

fragment DECIMAL_LITERAL 
 : ('0' | '1'..'9' DIGIT*)
 ;

fragment OCTAL_LITERAL 
 : '8#' ('0'..'7')+
 ;

fragment DIGIT
 : '0'..'9'
 ;

SPACE 
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

Parsing the input `"2#1111 8#77 0xff 16#ff 123"` will result in the following AST:

[image]

Since you've lost the information about what type of `Integer` each literal is, you will have to do this check in the `integer`-rule (the `-> {boolean-expression}? ...` things after the rewrite rules).

Comment: By simplifying my grammar to post a succinct example here I had to remove the reason for the question so I'll expand on what I'm trying to do. If you look at your second grammar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639783/float-literal-and-range-parameter-in-antlr you differentiate floats and 1..2 range operators by having only one lexer rule which uses a semantic predicate to resolve the ambiguity. I am using this approach in my grammar also which means all my numbers are grouped under a single lexer rule like this. But I want the numbers to parse into different trees, hence my question.