# Using floats in range and grammar mistakes?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to convert a LALR grammar to LL using ANTLR and I am running into a few problems. So far, I think converting the expressions into a Top-Down approach is straight forward to me. The problem is when I include Range (1..10) and (1.0..10.0) with floats.

I have tried to use the answer found here and somehow it is not even running correctly with my code, let alone solving a range of float, i.e. (float..float). 
[Float literal and range parameter in ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639783/float-literal-and-range-parameter-in-antlr)

Attached is a sample of my grammar that just focuses on this issue.

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
}

parse: 'in' rangeExpression ';'
     ;

rangeExpression : expression ('..' expression)?
                ;

expression : addingExpression (('=='|'!='|'<='|'<'|'>='|'>') addingExpression)*
           ;

addingExpression : multiplyingExpression (('+'|'-') multiplyingExpression)*
                 ;

multiplyingExpression : unaryExpression 
                        (('*'|'/'|'div') unaryExpression)*
                      ;

unaryExpression: ('+'|'-')* primitiveElement;   

primitiveElement : literalExpression
                 | id ('.' id)?
                 | '(' expression ')'
                 ;  

literalExpression : NUMBER
                  | BOOLEAN_LITERAL
                  | 'infinity'
                  ;              

id : IDENTIFIER
   ;

// L E X I C A L   R U L E S    
Range
 : '..'
 ;

NUMBER 
    : (DIGITS Range) => DIGITS          {$type=DIGITS;} 
    | (FloatLiteral) => FloatLiteral    {$type=FloatLiteral;}
    | DIGITS                            {$type=DIGITS;}
    ;   


// fragments
fragment FloatLiteral : Float;
fragment Float
 : DIGITS ( options {greedy = true; } : '.' DIGIT* EXPONENT?)
 | '.' DIGITS EXPONENT?
 | DIGITS EXPONENT
 ;

BOOLEAN_LITERAL : 'false' 
                | 'true'
                ;

IDENTIFIER : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ;
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;
```

Any reason why it is not even taking:

```
in 10;
```

or

```
in 10.0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following things are not correct:

- you're never matching a `FloatLiteral` in your `literalExpression` rule
- in every alternative of `NUMBER` you're changing the type of the token, therefor a `NUMBER` token will never be created

Something like this should work for both `11..22` and `1.1..2.2`:

```
...

literalExpression : INT
                  | BOOLEAN_LITERAL
                  | FLOAT
                  | 'infinity'
                  ;              

id : IDENTIFIER
   ;

// L E X I C A L   R U L E S    
Range
 : '..'
 ;

INT 
    : (DIGITS Range)=> DIGITS
    | DIGITS (('.' DIGITS EXPONENT? | EXPONENT) {$type=FLOAT;})?
    ; 

BOOLEAN_LITERAL : 'false' 
                | 'true'
                ;

IDENTIFIER : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ;
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;
fragment FLOAT : ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! But I believe if I am not mistaken that this doesn't solve (in 10..10;), i.e. a range of digits

Comment: I am not sure why I get this once I put in an EXPONENT: required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'e' ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndyM, not sure what you mean by "put in an EXPONENT". Do you mean you "feed" the parser an EXPONENT? That won't work since it is a fragment rule. If not, can you provide the input that is failing?

Comment: @AndyM, note that I chnaged the INT rule slightly, perhaps that is what you meant...

Answer (score 1):

To your question about handling `(1.0 .. 10.0)`:

Notice that parser rule `primitiveElement` defines an alternative as `'(' expression ')'`, but rule `expression` can never reach rule `rangeExpression`.

Consider redefining `expression` and `rangeExpression` like so:

```
expression : rangeExpression
           ;

rangeExpression : compExpression ('..' compExpression)?
                ;

compExpression : addingExpression (('=='|'!='|'<='|'<'|'>='|'>') addingExpression)*
               ;
```

This ensures that the `expression` rule sits above all forms of expressions and will work as expected in parentheses.

Comment: The way I have it now actually captures (10.0) but will never capture (10.0..20.0). Once I switched to your code, ANTLR v3 complained that rule '(' expression ') will never be reached.

Comment: @AndyM `(10.0)` is captured by the original grammar because the parentheses don't contain a range -- and a range is the only expression it won't accept in parentheses. I get no warnings from ANTLR v3.5 with the change shown in my answer. Make sure `primitiveElement` still has alternative `'(' expression ')'`. Is that the only warning you're getting?

Comment: Once I made @Bart changes, it worked! Thanks for noticing this error