# Parsing floating-point number and ranges separated by two periods with ANTLR 3

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I am working on a parser for a DSL that has two currently 'conflicting' features:

1. Floating-point numbers like `123.4`.
2. Ranges specified like `ID[2..5]` (ID is defined as `'a'..'z'+` and doesn't matter much. The part '[2..5]' matters most.

The test grammar that should parse it looks as follows:

```
grammar DotTest;

span returns [double value] 
  : ID'['e=INT'..'f=INT']' { /*some code to process the values*/ $value = (double)(Int32.Parse($e.text) + Int32.Parse($f.text)); } ;

num returns [double value]
  : DOUBLE {$value = double.Parse($DOUBLE.text); } ;

INT     : '0'..'9'+ ;
DOUBLE  : '0'..'9'+'.''0'..'9'+ ;
ID      : 'a'..'z'+ ;

WS      :   ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

**The problem:** the rule `span` cannot parse its input correctly, because it conflicts with `DOUBLE` token. The lexer tries to match `2..5` as a `DOUBLE` and fails. Here is how it looks in ANTLR Works:

[image: Mismatched token exception.]

What will be the correct way to solve this conflict and parse the two `INT`s in the `span` correctly?

**P.S.** I'm using ANTLR 3 and not ANTLR 4 as I'm going to generate a C# parser, which is not currently implemented in ANTLR 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float literal and range parameter in ANTLR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639783/float-literal-and-range-parameter-in-antlr)

Comment: FYI, there is an early release of the C# target for ANTLR4: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/1vhJja-k6NQ

Comment: @BartKiers I'm trying to adapt the answer to the linked question into my grammar. As soon as I'm done I will close the question as duplicate or post the grammar as solution.

Comment: @BartKiers that worked, thank you! Another question is _why_ it works. Hope to figure it out soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8642352/532647) (the second grammar) works fine. After I transformed the lexer rules to the following:

```
NUM : (INT RNG)=> INT {$type=INT;}  

    | (DOUBLE)=> DOUBLE {$type=DOUBLE;}

    | INT {$type=INT;};


fragment INT :  '0'..'9'+ ;
fragment DOUBLE :   '0'..'9'+'.''0'..'9'+ ;

RNG: '..' ;
```

parsing of intervals like `1..2` started working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The `DOUBLE` rule you posted above does not conflict with the `..` operator since the `'0'..'9'+` following the `'.'` contains at least one digit. The following alternate definition of `DOUBLE` would in fact conflict:

```
DOUBLE : '0'..'9'+ '.' '0'..'9'*;
```

I suspect you are using the interpreter in ANTLRWorks, which is known to give incorrect results in many cases.

Comment: Well, when I remove the DOUBLE rule from the grammar, everything works fine. If I set the range separator to be `,,` instead of `..`, everything works fine, too.

Comment: Indeed, I use the intepreter in ANTLRWorks, but I also use unit-tests covering the generated parser in C#.